# Interior, Boundary, Exterior points of subset of metric space of natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider the metric space of natural numbers with usual metric. And consider the set A= {1,2,3,4}.

Then what are the interior, exterior and boundary points of A?

- I think the set of interior points is equal to A={1,2,3,4} itself.

Because as the whole space is of natural numbers, i can find an open ball centered at any one point of A of radius 1/2 (say) which is contained in A as the ball contains only one point that is the center.

- The exterior should be the interior of complement of the set A. so here exterior of A is actually N-{1,2,3,4}

Am i right with these two things?

-Please explain the case of boundary points. I think they should be {1,2,3,4}. But still i want an explaination.

Comment: do you mean that $A\subset\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Everything you say can be easily verified by showing first that every subset of the naturals is open

Comment: no. it is contained in N. The whole space is taken to be the metric space of natural numbers. I have mentioned it in the begining of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about the interior and the exterior of $A$.

The boundary of $A$ consists of those $n\in\Bbb N$ such that every neighborhood contains at least an element of $A$ and at least one element of $\Bbb N\setminus A$. Therefore the boundary is empty, because:

- if $n\in A$, the open ball centered at $n$ with radius $1$ is $\{n\}$, and therefore it contains no element of $\Bbb N\setminus A$;
- if $n\notin A$, the open ball centered at $n$ with radius $1$ is $\{n\}$, and therefore it contains no element of $A$.